# Docker Node.js App failing to bind to $PORT on Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku

I have an app React, Nodejs containerized in Docker on Heroku it will fail to bind to the Heroku web port quite frequently. For the express server I have the PORT variable set to `process.env.PORT || 5000` I'm new to docker but believe the problem is within the docker set up.

server.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const notesRouter = require('./routes/notes');
const userRouter = require('./routes/userSettings');
const config = require('./config/config.json');


const environment = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production';

console.log('Host environment', process.env.NODE_ENV);

main().catch((err) => console.log(err));

async function main() {
    const connect = await mongoose.connect(config[environment].mongodb, {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
        useFindAndModify: false,
    });
    console.log(`MongoDB connected: ${(connect.connection.host)}`);
    return;
}


const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use('/notes', notesRouter);
app.use('/api/users', userRouter);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' || process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    const root = require('path').join(__dirname, '..', 'client', 'build');
    app.use(express.static(root));
    app.use('/users', notesRouter);
    app.use('/api/users', userRouter);
    app.get('*', function(req, res) {
        res.sendFile('index.html', { root });
    });
}

app.listen((process.env.PORT || 5000), () => {
    console.log(`App listening on port ${process.env.port || 5000}`);
});
```

If the problem is here with the port in the Docker file how do I set the port for Heroku ?

docker-compose.yml

```
services: 

  server: 
    build: 
      context: "."
      dockerfile: ./server/Dockerfile
    container_name: note_script-app
    depends_on: 
      - mongo
    environment: 
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports: 
      - "5000:${PORT}"
    restart: always
    volumes: 
      - /Desktop/Users/adam/desktop/Code/Apps/Docker_example
version: "3.9"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node as prod

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package*.json ./

COPY . .

RUN npm install

ENV NODE_ENV=production

CMD ["npm","start"]
```